Artinian simple algebras with involution
Let $A$ be an Artinian simple $K$-algebra with involution $*$. The algebra $A$ has a primitive idempotent $e$, and $D_e:=eAe$ is a division $K$-algebra due to Schur's lemma and the isomorphism $(eAe)^{op} \cong \text{End}_A(Ae)$. Due to simplicity all $D_e$ are isomorphic for each primitive idempotent $e$ of $A$.
Now my questions are:
When is $D_e$ involution invariant?
What should be the relation between $e$ and $*$ so that we are able to claim $$\forall a\in A, \exists b \in A,\ ebe=e^*ae^*?$$
I want the answer for the case when $A$ is a central simple $K$-algebra and also when it is not central simple.
If we identify $(A,*) \cong (\text{Mat}_n(D),{}^t\bar{})$, where $\bar{}$ denotes the involution in $D$ and ${}^t\bar{}$ is the involution $\bar{}$ twisted with the transpoese, then $eAe$ is involution invariant iff $e$ corresponds to $E_{ii}$, the matrix with all entries zero except for 1 at $(i,i)$-position.
However, I have a problem in this argument. We know that, by the Wedderburn theorem, $A \cong \text{Mat}_n(D_e)$ for every primitive idempotent $e$, but how we can say this isomorphism preserves involution? And how we can even restrict $*$ to $D_e$ when we do not know whether $D_e$ is involution invariant or not. It is like a vicious cycle; I do not know where I should start.

Don't you want $e$ to be a projection so that $e^*=e$?  After all $e$ is the unique nonzero idempotent in eAe

Does there always exist such an idempotent?
